# Assign Django default model value as count of a foreign field key

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

I am figuring out how i can add the sum value of fields to a foreign key definition

```
class TestInfo(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.ForeignKey(TestQuestion, on_delete=models.PROTECT, to_field="correct_answer" default=self.get_count())
    def get_count(self):
        TestQuestion.objects.filter(user=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, test_number=TestQuestion.test_number).count(correct_answer=True)
```

Whenever there is an create or edit it should populate the value to customer_name. I will implement the save value for TestInfo.customer_name when there is a addition or change of list of values or change of value in the TestQuestion model's save/edit.

Comment: You can set [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#pre-save) singal on `TestInfo` and set the value produced by `get_count` (probably staticmethod will be better in this case) there.

Comment: Thank you. Should work. Can you put this as the answer. I will mark it resolved.

Comment: You're welcome! Sure, I added this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#pre-save) singal on `TestInfo` and set the value produced by `get_count` (probably staticmethod will be better in this case) there.